# bind- value to doesn't work in radio button in blazor

Tags: forms, radio-button, blazor

For the following code, for some reason the selection of the radio buttons binds x.MyCapability with -> "on" instead of the label of the button (let's assume the labels of the radio element are *a ,*b and *c):

```
@foreach (var capability in myList)
             {
                 <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="MyCapability" SelectedValue="MyCapability" @bind-value="x.MyCapability" />
                    @capability <text> &nbsp; &nbsp;</text>
                </label>
            }
```

how can I link x.MyCapability with a, b or c?
.NetCore 3.1

Answer (score 0):

You are binding in a wrong way, here is the way you can

Your html

```
<div>Your Capability: @MyCapability</div>

<div>
    @foreach (var capability in myList)
    {
        <div>
            <label>@capability.MyCapability</label>
            <input type="radio"
               name="@capability.MyCapability"
               @onchange=@(() => MyCapability = capability.MyCapability)
               checked="@(capability.MyCapability==MyCapability)">
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Here is the code behind

```
@code{    
    private string MyCapability = "a";

    private List<Capabilities> myList = new()
        {
            new Capabilities()
            {
                MyCapability = "a"
            },
            new Capabilities()
            {
                MyCapability = "b"
            },
            new Capabilities()
            {
                MyCapability = "c"
            }
        };

    public class Capabilities
    {
        public string MyCapability { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When you select any option it will be update in above div